# (Reference request) Random vectors with "locally" uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be discrete random variables which are possibly dependent on each other. We are given the following information these variables: when holding $X_i$ fixed for all $i \neq j$, the probability distribution of $X_j$ is a uniform distribution over some set (we can make the assumption that $X_1$ and $X_n$ are singletons and that for $1 < j < n$ this set is determined exclusively by $X_{j-1}$ and $X_{j+1}$ if it helps).

I am interested in whether this kind of setting has been studied, and particularly, in what we can say about the distribution of the vector $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, and would appreciate any insight or references.

Comment: If this is a complicated way of talking about order statistics ($X_{j-1} \lt X_j \lt X_{j+1}$) then the answer may be yes.

Comment: @Henry  $X_j$ can be arbitrarily large; only the range of its (uniform) distribution is decided by $j-1$ and $j+1$